# How to Invoke-Command an uninst.exe remotely in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to uninstall a software on a remote computer by executing the uninst.exe via Invoke-Command and Start-Process. There is no response.

This my code:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName xxx –ScriptBlock {
    Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SonicWALL\SSL-VPN\NetExtender\uninst.exe'
}
```

There is no error message, nothing to indicate that it didn't work, but NetExtende is still installed. If I run the same command locally on the computer:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SonicWALL\SSL-VPN\NetExtender\uninst.exe'
```

it works.

The connection to the remote computer works as well. When I `Invoke-Command` other stuff, for example creating a txt file, it works.

When I did some research, I often come upon similar problems, but not exactly the same and no solution so far. But I have the feeling it has something to do with the path and the spaces inside it, because that was a common theme.

EDIT: I think the problem is with Invoke-Command and Start-Process. I don't get any process started on the remote computer, regardless if it is a path with spaces or not.

Comment: when you start the exe on your computer, does it require input? (try `& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SonicWALL\SSL-VPN\NetExtender\uninst.exe'`)

Comment: @T-Me Unfortunatly the &-Operator does not work as well. But you are right, I have to click Yes or No to some question if I execute the .exe on the computer.

Comment: That is the problem. `start-process` will just start this exe. And `start-process` does not produce any output on it's own. The process is running (probably multiple times by now) and awaiting input. The question is if the exe is build with optional parameters so that you could start it quiet or if you need other means to uninstall it. (something like `msiexec /x {product-code} /quiet`)

Comment: @T-Me It is optional I think. It asks me "Do you want to remove all the existing Connection profiles?" and it uninstalls in any case, regardless if I click yes or no. Afterwards there is a: "Program was successfully removed from your computer.", which I can confirm with "Ok".

But if I use "Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden" it changes nothing.

Comment: The documentation says about the parameter `-FilePath` *"Specifies a local script that this cmdlet runs on one or more remote computers."* So I don't think you can run a local executable on a remote computer that way. You need to copy it to the remote host first.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The .exe is on the remote computer.

Comment: In that case `Invoke-Command -Computer xxx -ScriptBlock {& 'C:\path\to\your.exe'}` should work. If it doesn't you need to investigate what goes wrong on the remote host (check eventlog, check uninstall log if the uninstaller produces one, run uninstaller with debug options if it provides such).

Comment: To add to @T-Me's comments: https://www.itninja.com/question/sonicwall-netextender-silent-install suggests that adding `/S` _may_ work to run the uninstaller silently (and use `Start-Process` only if you want to run _asynchronously_, i.e if you want `Invoke-Command` to return before the uninstaller completes; otherwise, use `&`, as suggested).